# unit test in Vue with Karma and Webpack

Tags: unit-testing, webpack, vue.js, karma-mocha

As title, i try the unit test with Karma in lastest version of Vue.
i am sure the `test` file is currect because i run it in defalut vue appliction.It runs well.
But when i run `npm run unit` in my working application, i gives error info below:

```
Chrome 65.0.3325 (Mac OS X 10.13.3) ERROR
Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined
at webpack:/external%20%22Vue%22:1:0 <- index.js:1418
```

i googled this for a long time, but got nothing. Is anyone met this before?

Comment: Post the code of your test script

Comment: my test code is ok, because i didn't modify since vue-cli created it, and i try renew a application, it runs well.

Comment: We have no idea what to see if you don’t post that

Answer (score 0):

after rest for a while, i think through it. Why it will lint `Vue is not defined`? And how does the test component work? I wonder it may be caused by my Vue import Strategies. In order to reduce the time of page opened in browser, i import `vue` and other packages using `CDN`, i guess it can't accepted by Karma.I tried to roll back,and run `npm run unit`,fortunately, everything runs well.

```
Chrome 65.0.3325 (Mac OS X 10.13.3): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.034 secs / 0.011 secs)
TOTAL: 1 SUCCESS
```

thank you, guys.Think and solve the problem is really magic and exciting.